# How to calculate the row-variance of each group?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame(group = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'),
                   X1 = rnorm(5),
                   X2 = rnorm(5),
                   X3 = rnorm(5))
```

I would like to calculate the variance of each group under the column group. So variance of A would be variance of the first two rows and so forth. Ideally, I would like to compare the variance within a group and between groups; output would look like a correlation matrix. Desired Output:

| Variance Table | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | var of A | var of A+B | var of A+C |
| B | var of B+A | var of B | var of B+C |
| C | var of C+A | var of C+B | var of C |

Where var of A+B means it's the variance of the first three rows.

Comment: (1) Is there any meaning to the columns in your data? For instance, for the "A" components in your variance table, are there six values, two rows of three columns? (2) Can you please fill out real values of your expected output? Since we can't have your random numbers, please add `set.seed` before your definition of `data`, or you can provide the output from `dput(data)` in your question, and we'll have the same contents without worrying about the randomness. Thanks!

Comment: (3) Please confirm: "var of A+B" means the variance of the combined unlisted values of both, so if `vecA` is an unlisted vector of the six values in the `A` group, and `vecB` is the unlisted vector of the three values in the `B` group, then that cell in the variance table would be `var(c(vecA, vecB))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```r
out <- outer(
  setNames(nm=unique(data$group)), setNames(nm=unique(data$group)),
  Vectorize(function(a, b) var(unlist(subset(data, group %in% c(a, b), select = -group))))
)
out
#           A         B         C
# A 1.1626004 1.3823834 0.9368846
# B 1.3823834 0.8256655 0.8212769
# C 0.9368846 0.8212769 0.7254770
```

Breakdown/verification: for "var A + B",

```r
vecA <- unname(unlist(subset(data, group == "A", select = X1:X3)))
vecA
# [1]  1.3709584 -0.5646982 -0.1061245  1.5115220  1.3048697  2.2866454
vecB <- unname(unlist(subset(data, group == "B", select = X1:X3)))
vecB
# [1]  0.36312841 -0.09465904 -1.38886070
var(c(vecA, vecB))
# [1] 1.382383
```

Note: the use of `setNames(nm=.)` is a trick that assigns names to themselves: see that `setNames(nm=c("A","B"))` is the same as `setNames(c("A","B"),nm=c("A","B"))`, so when `object=` (first arg) is not provided, it uses `nm=` for *both* the objects and their names. Self-naming.

One reason this is useful is that `outer` is going to preserve the names of its arguments in the column and row names. One may *want* (and expect) them to be in alphabetic order, but `unique(.)` preserves the natural sort,

```r
unique(c("A","C","B","C"))
# [1] "A" "C" "B"
unique(c("A","B","C","C"))
# [1] "A" "B" "C"
```

So if `data$group` did not already have the first occurrence of each in the expected order, then the column *names* (and therefore order of the values) would change:

```r
set.seed(2022)
data <- data[sample(5),]
data
#   group         X1          X2         X3
# 4     C  0.6328626  2.01842371 -0.2787888
# 3     B  0.3631284 -0.09465904 -1.3888607
# 2     A -0.5646982  1.51152200  2.2866454
# 1     A  1.3709584 -0.10612452  1.3048697
# 5     C  0.4042683 -0.06271410 -0.1333213
outer(
  setNames(nm=unique(data$group)), setNames(nm=unique(data$group)),
  Vectorize(function(a, b) var(unlist(subset(data, group %in% c(a, b), select = -group))))
)
#           C         B         A
# C 0.7254770 0.8212769 0.9368846
# B 0.8212769 0.8256655 1.3823834
# A 0.9368846 1.3823834 1.1626004
```

In this case, the use of `setNames(nm=.)` is ensuring that regardless of the order of `unique(data$group)`, there is no doubt which column/row pairings we're looking at.

---

Starting data:

```r
set.seed(42)
data <- data.frame(group = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'),
                   X1 = rnorm(5),
                   X2 = rnorm(5),
                   X3 = rnorm(5))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I couldn't get back online for the comments. Your solution works and is exactly what I was looking for. My one question the row and column name of out would be in the order of data$group right? So I can do row.names(out) <- colnames(out) <- unique(data$group)?

Comment: I don't think `unique` is the right way to go, since `unique` tends to preserve the natural order. For instance, one might expect the column/row names to be A,B,C, but see that `unique(c("A","C","B","C"))` is not necessarily that. I'm making an edit that will clear this up without ambiguity.